# How do the points work when creating a rectangle to pass to e.Graphics.FillEllipse in order to create a circle?

Tags: c#, winforms, paint

In a panel's `OnPaint` event, I'm creating a circle like this:

```
e.Graphics.FillEllipse(
   new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(128, 0, 0, 0)), 
   new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100));
```

It creates a decent enough circle that looks like this (the green part is just the form's background):

[image: circle]

But I need it bigger. So I started playing around with the `Rectangle`, but no matter what combination of arguments I pass to it, I can't make a bigger circle. I always end up making so weird half/quarter shape thing.

So how do the arguments work in this case?

Comment: Make sure your panel's size is bigger than your `Rectangle`

Comment: You should just increase the size of the Rectangle (for example new Rectangle(0, 0, 200, 200) ). Are you sure that the panel is big enough. Maybe the figure gets cut out because the panel cannot contain all of it.

Comment: @Fung Ah. Gotcha. I thought my understanding of `FillEllipse` was wrong. That explains why the circle in my example is cutoff at the bottom a little. So, this works. Please submit the answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you increase the `Rectangle`'s Size, make sure the container control's (i.e. `Panel`) Size is big enough to fully display the `Rectangle`, and hence the circle too.